# Jelastic demo сервер

Tags: java, servlet

На *Jelastic* демо сервере развернул свой *Java* проект но как не пытался запустить возвращает `404` ошибку, а на локальном все в порядке с чем это связано?

на web.xml  `<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>`

на *Jelastic*-е когда развернул дал такой же имя  `test`

и когда запускаю возвращает `404` ошибку

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(Model model){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможно с регистрацией сервлета что-то накрутили. Покажите web.xml , а также класс servlet-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для корректного применения необходимого Вам url-pattern'a в файле web.xml
необходимо заменить `<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>` на паттерн такого формата:

```
<url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
```

**Обновление**

Основной проблемой здесь является то, что IntelliJ, в отличие от Eclipse, автоматически не компилирует класс, когда он сохраняется, даже если Вы выбирали *Build on save*. Вам нужно настроить проект, как указано [в документации](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-reload-springloaded-gradle-and-intellij).

Comment: не помогло почему то

Comment: Какую IDE Вы использывали для создания данного Java проекта?

Comment: Intellij___idea